# Showing that $A[x] \cap A[x^{-1}] $ is an integral extension of $A$ when $x$ is invertible and $x$ belongs to a bigger ring containing $A$

Tags: commutative-algebra, integral-extensions

I have a problem-
$A, B$ are rings such that $A \subset B$ and  $x$ is an invertible element in $B$.          I have to show that that the ring $T = A[x] \cap A[x^{-1}]$ is an integral extension of $A$.
I first tried to show it by definition, taking an element in $T$, assuming it satisfies a n degree polynomial and using other results to show that this element is integral over $A$. But I don't know how an element of $T$ looks like so I don't think this approach is any good.

Next, I thought maybe we can write $T$ as $A[y]$ where $y$ is some element of $B$ in terms of $x$ and show that this $y$ is integral over $A$. But I don't know if that is possible.

I would appreciate it if someone could suggest some better way to solve this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: I answered this question long time ago. Search please.

Comment: I found it, thanks. But I still want to see if there're any alternate approaches. Should I delete the post? Or not?

Comment: @user26857 Could you please add a link to your previous answer?